# Testing click event in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here is a simple subcomponent that reveals an `answer` to a question when the button is clicked:

```js
const Question = ({ question, answer }) => {
    const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false)
    return (
        <>
           <article>
               <header>
                    <h2 data-testid="question">{question}</h2>
                    <button onClick={() => setShowAnswer(!showAnswer)}>
                        {
                            !showAnswer ? <FiPlusCircle /> : <FiMinusCircle />
                        }
                    </button>
               </header>
               {
                   showAnswer && <p data-testid="answer">{answer}</p>
               }
           </article>
        </>
    )
}

export default Question;
```

I am trying to test that when the `button` is clicked, the `onClick` attached is called once and the a `<p>` element appears on the screen:

```js
const onClick = jest.fn()

test('clicking the button toggles an answer on/off', () => {
    render(<Question />);
    
    const button = screen.getByRole('button')
    fireEvent.click(button)
    
    expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('answer')).toBeInTheDocument()
    
    fireEvent.click(button)

    expect(screen.getByTestId('answer')).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    screen.debug()
    
})
```

RTL says that `onClick` is not called at all (in the UI it is, as the result is as expected)

Also, if I want to test that this button really toggles the `answer` element (message should come on and off) how would I test for that?

If I add another `fireEvent.click()` to the test (simulating the second click on the button which should trigger the `answer` element off), and add

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId('answer')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
```

RTL will just not find that element (which is good, I guess, it means it has been really toggled off the DOM). What assertion would you use for this test to pass for that case?

Comment: what is fireEvent

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Couple of issues with your approach.

First, creating an `onClick` mock like that won't mock your button's `onClick` callback. The callback is internal to the component and you don't have access to it from the test. What you could do instead is test the result of triggering the `onClick` event, which in this case means verifying that `<FiMinusCircle />` is rendered instead of `<FiPlusCircle />`.

Second, `p` is not a valid role - RTL tells you which roles are available in the DOM if it fails to find the one you searched for. The `paragraph` element doesn't have an inherent accessibility role, so you're better off accessing it by its content with `getByText` instead.

Here's an updated version of the test:

```js
test('clicking the button toggles an answer on/off', () => {
    render(<Question question="Is RTL great?" answer="Yes, it is." />);
    const button = screen.getByRole('button')
    
    fireEvent.click(button)
    // Here you'd want to test if `<FiMinusCircle />` is rendered.
    expect(/* something from FiMinusCircle */).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText('Yes, it is.')).toBeInTheDocument()
    
    fireEvent.click(button)
    // Here you'd want to test if `<FiPlusCircle />` is rendered.
    expect(/* something from FiPlusCircle */).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText('Yes, it is.')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case this worked:

```
it('Does click event', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Component />);

    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector('.your-btn-classname'));

    // click evt was triggered
});
```

Comment: querySelector is not recommended.  See this [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-container-to-query-for-elements)

Comment: @IsaacPak My organization has its own component library. This means common DOM elements are prefaced by the component library name (as in <org-button> instead of <button>). This means I can't target components in the usual ways. querySelector() is often the best option for this situation.